# Response body is always empty but the response code is 200 while fetching a JSON response from a webserver

Tags: python, rest, http

I'm trying to get a JSON response from a specific link (see python code below) using python's requests module.
When I test the link in Firefox's RESTer (or just copy it into the browser's address bar), it returns information as it should:

*fetchJSON_comment98({"productAttr":null,"productCommentSummary":{"skuId":100020974898,"averageScore":5,"defaultGoodCount":0,"defaultGoodCountStr":"10��+","commentCount":0,"commentCountStr":"10��+","goodCount":0,"goodCountStr":"2.1��+","goodRate":0.97,"goodRateShow":97,"generalCount":0,"generalCountStr":"200+","generalRate":0.02,"generalRateShow":2,"poorCoun ... (truncated)*

Headers:

- *Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 09:25:31 GMT*
- *Content-Type: text/html;charset=GBK*
- *Transfer-Encoding: chunked*
- *Connection: close*
- *Vary: Accept-Encoding*
- *Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=502398ABD60D51F774B1E90EEF32F818.s1; Path=/ jwotest_product=99; Domain=club.jd.com; Expires=Wed, 16-Jun-2021 09:25:30 GMT; Path=/*
- *Server: jfe*
- *Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=7776000*

The same is shown in Firefox's network inspector:
[Firefox Network Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASHQQ.png)

But when I try the following code from python 3.7:

```
from requests import Session

url = "https://club.jd.com/comment/productPageComments.action?callback=fetchJSON_comment98&productId=100020974898&score=0&sortType=6&page=0&pageSize=10&isShadowSku=0&fold=1"

headers = {"Host": "club.jd.com",
           "Pragma": "no-cache",
           "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}

s = Session()
resp = s.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
```

I get a HTTP 200 response and an empty response body with the following response headers:

```
'date' (1890118560096) = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('Date', 'Wed, 09 Jun 2021 09:33:02 GMT')
'content-type' (1890118524080) = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=GBK')
'transfer-encoding' (1890118269376) = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')
'connection' (1890118524464) = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('Connection', 'close')
'vary' (1890118560376) = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('Vary', 'Accept-Encoding')
'content-encoding' (1890118568528) = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('Content-Encoding', 'gzip')
'server' (1890118560880) = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('Server', 'jfe')
'strict-transport-security' (1890118632112) = {tuple} <class 'tuple'>: ('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=7776000')
```

I have tried adding cookies with CookieJar or copying it from the browser's response or making my own but none of that worked. Tried many solutions listed here on Stackoverflow, but no success...

Please help me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the user-agent header. Change the header to whatever is going in the browser and the code works. You could read up more on the user-agent header format here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

```
from requests import Session

url = "https://club.jd.com/comment/productPageComments.action?callback=fetchJSON_comment98&productId=100020974898&score=0&sortType=6&page=0&pageSize=10&isShadowSku=0&fold=1"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36"}

s = Session()
resp = s.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
```